# Macro that pastes formatted tables from excel into ppt presentation crashes irregulary

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I created macro in excel that uses excel report to copy and paste large number of tables into power point presentation. Tables are pasted using 'Keep source formatting' method and after pasting macro changes font size to 7 if the font is smaller and places the table in correct position on the slide. The problem is that the macro is skipping between the two applications and each pasting is time consuming so sometimes the macro crashes/frozen - for example when running the macro for the same report various number of times I receive different results - sometimes presentation is produced successfully, few minutes later the macro crashes on slide 15 and in another run it crashes on slide number 41 for exactly the same report. Is there a way to run the macro as a background process to enable excel performance with no errors or any way to avoid excel crushing from time to time...I would appreciate any advise/suggestions!

Below is the code of supporting macro that I use to paste the table and change font size when required table range is copied:

```
Sub PastewithSourceFormatting_table(iSlide As Integer, table_name As Object)
Dim shapes_number As Integer
Dim shapes_number_new As Integer
Dim v_size As Byte
Dim row_num As Integer
Dim col_num As Integer
shapes_number_new = 0
shapes_number = 0
v_size = 0
row_num = 0
col_num = 0

  Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(iSlide)
  PPSlide.Select


shapes_number = PPSlide.Shapes.Count

Do Until shapes_number_new = shapes_number + 1
With PPSlide
    PPApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    PPApp.CommandBars.ReleaseFocus
    shapes_number_new = .Shapes.Count
End With
Loop

 Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))


    Application.CutCopyMode = False

  Set table_name = PPSlide.Shapes.Item(shapes_number_new)


 '---------check font size

v_size = table_name.Table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size
row_num = table_name.Table.Rows.Count
col_num = table_name.Table.Columns.Count

If v_size < 7 Then

Dim i, j As Integer

For i = 1 To row_num
For j = 1 To col_num
If table_name.Table.Cell(i, j).Shape.TextFrame.HasText = msoTrue Then
table_name.Table.Cell(i, j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 7
End If
Next j
Next i

Else
End If

 Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))


End Sub
```